# Can openssl_random_pseudo_bytes and/or /dev/random ever lead to performance issues?

Tags: php, openssl

I use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` for cryptographically secure randomness. Does this function use /dev/random/ or /dev/urandom? I've read the former is more secure than the latter but can “block” if enough randomness isn't available.

Is this blocking just a delay and if so can it ever lead to performance issues? I read the blog post *[Better Random Numbers in PHP using /dev/urandom](https://codeascraft.com/2012/07/19/better-random-numbers-in-php-using-devurandom/)* which states:

> /dev/urandom is a special psuedo-file on unix-like operating systems
>   that generates “mostly random” bytes and is non-blocking. /dev/random
>   (with no “u“) is for truly cryptographic applications such as key
>   generation and is blocking. Once you exhaust it’s supply of randomness
>   it blocks until it distills new randomness from the environment.
>   Therefore, you don’t want to use /dev/random in your web application.

Is that true? Can openssl_random_pseudo_bytes and/or /dev/random ever lead to performance issues?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have never used `/dev/random`. But I have used Win32 Cryptography API on Windows to generate random number. I have compared the performance of OpenSSL and CAPI and OpenSSL turns out faster than Windows counterpart. But I have tested in a C++ program, not in PHP.

So, I think that OpenSSL must not be slower than `/dev/random` if not faster. OpenSSL uses system call for seeding, not for generation.

It must not turn into bottleneck. But you should profile the result before any decision. I have not found any problem on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, so does openssl_random_pseudo_bytes not actually use /dev/random? I thought it did.

Comment: Default engine does not use. It only uses for seeding. Generally, seeding is done only for 1 time. Hence, for one time, it should not be bottleneck.

Comment: Can you elaborate on “seeding is done only for 1 time”?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Computational_methods
Generally computational method is used to generate random number. First value which is used is known as seed. And for good random number, this seed should be random or unique each time. Hence, many applications choose time or some other secure random number. OpenSSL might choose random number generated by /dev/random.